# About Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgeries?

Tags: php

I found these couple lines of code on the internet and the goal is to prevent CSRF using a one-time token. **Since the hidden value can be easily read from the source code, i am trying to figure out what makes this code prevent cross site request forgeries? any idea?**

```
 **form.php** 
  <?php 
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    ?>    
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <p>
    Symbol: <input type="text" name="symbol" /><br />
    Shares: <input type="text" name="shares" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
    </p>
    </form>


**process.php**
   <?php

    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        /* Valid Token */
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: If you read the wikipedia page about it you will certainly understand why it is useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Answer (score 0):

the token is generated for each response and the attacker normally doesn't have access to the content of the page being attacked.

Comment: If i access the page once then the token and the session are created. Meaning that i can look at the source code and grab that token. Now without destroying the session, i can go to a separate script and post to that process.php by providing the token. That is why i am confused.

Comment: But you are not the one attacking. This is just not how the CSRF attacks work (hence a comment to the original question to read the description of what CSRF is and how it works).  Generally, CSRF works over a different attack vector.

Comment: I think i got it confused with "Form spoofing".

Answer (score 0):

The idea of CSRF is that a user could not do an action he did not intend to do.

For example a user could be logged in as an administrator at a wordpress website, while his login is valid he will browse to some other site which contains malicious code that posts to change password in the user wordpress site.

Because the login is valid (the session exists) the request passes by the user verification but fails because it is missing the token for that specific action (which is generated each time the form is viewed).

Answer (score 0):

The token is uniquely generated for each session and stored into the global session variable. When the site is accessed by the attacker via iframe or whatever form of attack they used, the token that is generated [hopefully] will not match the token stored into the DB (in this case, posted to process.php). Since the tokens do not match, the attacker will not be able to access the content in the if-statement in process.php.