# What is the best solution to form spoofing?

Tags: php

What is the best solution to "form spoofing" besides filtering the inputs?

I understand the followings:

1. Referrer can be spoofed
2. Telnet can be used to fool the server
3. Client side filtering can be bypassed
4. i understand that i should avoid GET
5. I can use Captcha

How can i prevent somebody to post to my form processing scripts from anywhere?

Comment: Using a CAPTCHA is the only way I could think of, but in theory it is absolutely impossible when using HTTP.

Comment: `Avoiding GET` is a common misconception. You already listed netcat/telnet, but any HTTP client (wget or curl) can just as easily send custom `POST` requests. Depending on POST is security by obscurity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone can manually post a form, they can do it automatically too. There's no way to stop that besides moderation. You can make it harder by using captcha's. But personally I hate captcha's, because they are just a solution made up by lazy moderators to make the users solve their problems.

Comment: well, it helps translate books.

Comment: If they want me to translate a book, they can just ask. Until then, it just makes it harder and more annoying for users to prove they are human.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use tokens.

http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: Token is not the solution for this kind of attack see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188916/about-preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries

Answer (score 0):

Not much really. Every client-side check can be spoofed or bypassed. Some authentication method is best, either using [HTTP Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or a simple system you coded yourself with sessions.

Comment: Even with auth you can still send the request from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the best solution is necessarily, but you can use a session variable on the script that should have generated the form and check it in the script that the form POSTs to.  You can md5 the variable contents and make it something somewhat random for increased security as well.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is why do you *want* to prevent people from being able to post to your webpage from anywhere?  Your webpage should be prepared to accept any input no matter where it comes from.  There are measures you can take to reduce automatic posting such as tokens, but there is no way you can prevent it completely.

Instead of trying to prevent it, though, I would welcome it.  Advertise your cross-site post API and profit.

Postel's law:

> TCP implementations should follow a general principle of robustness: be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others.

Answer (score 0):

Set a hidden input on the form that's equal to the md5 value of a string made up of the session id + a secret "salt" string value.  Then, when you process the form, you can get the session id, add the secret value, and compare the mp5 out of that to the value that was passed with the form.

Comment: People can see the hidden value so that is not real security.